Ways of initializing complex member variables in C++
I have a class for managing some GUI-related stuff, like a tgui::Gui object.
I would like to store this Gui object as a member variable in my class, but the problem is when I try to initialize it.
The following does not work:
.h file
class BTGui
{
public:
    BTGui();

private:
    tgui::Gui m_gui;
};

.cpp file
BTGui::BTGui()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window{sf::VideoMode({1024, 800}), "MyTitle", sf::Style::None};
    m_gui = tgui::Gui{window};
}

The problem is that there is no copy constructor:

Object of type 'tgui::Gui' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted.

I tried using the initializer list like:
BTGui::BTGui() : m_gui{tgui::Gui{sf::RenderWindow{sf::VideoMode({1024, 800}), "MyTitle", sf::Style::None}}} {}

but that does not compile:

error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'tgui::SFML_GRAPHICS::Gui'

and

note: Reason: cannot convert from 'sf::RenderWindow' to 'const tgui::SFML_GRAPHICS::Gui'

If this was a simple variable, I would just use the initializer list, but I need to create the window object too, and let's assume that the window size was given by the user.
What is the "best" way of doing this?
By "best", I mean a simple way that would work for multiple variables as well.

Have you tried using an initializer list? You are default constructing an object and trying to invoke the copy constructor; why not just construct the object you want?

Because m_gui must be constructed, you can add a Base class. The Base class is to construct the window instance. Then in the initializer list, the m_gui can be constructed on the window instance created before in the Base

Important here is that the sf::Window needs to live longer than the m_gui variable, as its destructor closes the window again. So your entire problem stems from not having a window around to construct the gui on

@dalfaB Could you please elaborate on this? Do you mean to add a base class to BTGui which holds the window object? and then to use that in the BTGui initialization?

@UnholySheep Alright, but why is it a problem to  construct the window as I am initializing m_gui? Why does the window need to exist before?

@Noxet, yes. like struct WndHolder { WndHolder(int x,int y) : windows(......) {} protected: sf::RenderWindow window; };. But here you can simply add windows as a BTGui field before m_gui and create both in the initializer list.

@dalfaB I see, and yes that would work. It does not feel like a clean solution to have to add a class and inherit just for a single variable. I also don't want to have a windows field in my class since m_gui already contains the window itself. It also feels like this would not scale well, if lets say window depended on yet another object, would we need 2 levels of inheritance then?

@Brendan See my edited answer :)

m_gui does not contain the window itself. It contains a reference to the window. If the window gets destroyed before the GUI is destroyed your program will have a lot of issues

@UnholySheep That's correct, it just has a pointer to a window. So would it be possible do new sf::RenderWindow... in the initialization list? or is this just bad?
I can initialize the gui without parameters, and then in the ctor create a window and call m_gui.setWindow
